# Missing time series for UK Summer time change - r

Tags: r

I am seeing missing timseries data corresponding to GMT time change for Summer. I guess this might also be for Winter. I have two parts of query.
How to generate the missing timeseries from the code below. The table is in a xts format.
How to filter the records by time that will include the missing time series once generated. This is only a sample dataset. Thanks.

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2022-03-27 00:58:00")
interval <- 2
end <- as.POSIXct("2022-03-27 03:00:00")
missing_timestamp <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end))
head(missing_timestamp)
        TIMESTAMP
1 2022-03-27 00:58:00
2 2022-03-27 02:00:00
3 2022-03-27 02:02:00
4 2022-03-27 02:04:00
5 2022-03-27 02:06:00
6 2022-03-27 02:08:00
```

**Update:**
Linked to the second query, when below code is executed for time between 00hrs and 02:06hrs all data is returned rather than the first four records.

```
a <- missing_timestamp %>% filter(TIMESTAMP > ymd_hms("2022-03-27 00:00:00") & TIMESTAMP < ymd_hms("2022-03-27 02:06:00"))
```

Comment: There are no missing times. The "missing times" simply do not exist. The clocks go forward by 1 hour at 01:00 with the time zone changing from GMT to BST.

Comment: You can't generate times that don't exist with R data time objects. Just like you can't create date of January 35, 2022. Perhaps you want to use a time standard like UTC that does not observe any daylight saving time changes. Dates and times should follow the rules defined by your system locale.

Comment: @MrFlick and Allan - Thanks for your inputs. In regard with the second part of the query, when I attempt to query the data frame based on date I am not getting the desired output. Example, below code returns all records from the table rather than only few records. I wonder if this is linked to "missing times". 
a <- missing_timestamp %>% 
  filter(TIMESTAMP > ymd_hms("2022-03-27 00:00:00") & TIMESTAMP < ymd_hms("2022-03-27 02:08:00"))

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show with your example. That filter would seem to include all records in the sample. What exactly were you expecting to be returned? Perhaps the problem is that you are trying to do exact matches on date/time values? Note that the quirks of floating point math are at play when working with date/time  values. Maybe update your question to make it clear what the problem is and show what you expect to happen.

Comment: @MrFlick - updated the query to bring more clarity, thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating your results. Note that `lubridate::ymd_hms()` will return dates in the UTC format while `as.POSIXct` will use your default locale. To be safe you should either make sure they are both the same (either UTC or GMT)

Comment: @MrFlick - Thanks for your time as well as your observation on this. Much appreciated.